# How to print web page with a different stylesheet other than print.css

Tags: java, html, css, printing

I've already got a print.css that manages print outs of a page but I want to create basic-print.css which prints out very basic information.  How would I create a button that prints the web page out using basic-print.css instead of print.css?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: quick example of what I'm trying to achieve...

1. CTRL+P (or File > Print) == Use print.css
2. Hit button called "Basic Print" == Use basic-print.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an idea, but have you tried loading the basic-print.css file with JavaScript?

I'm thinking of something like (using the jQuery library):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#print-basic-button').click(function(){
       $('link').first().removeAttr('href').attr('href', 'basic-print.css');
    });
});
```

Comment: I've given that a try but when I hit the button nothing seems to happen... Have I done the button wrong? <button id="print-basic-button">Print Basic</button>

Comment: you then need to still do a the CTRL+P combination. It should change the link tag in your head tag so it uploads your basic-print.css file instead in case the user want's to print. Is the page static HTML or is it generated through PHP?

Comment: It isn't changing the CSS reference in the <head> tag at all on click hence why I checked the button code.  The page itself is generated by ASP/VBScript but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I was asking because I'm wondering if it wouldn't be easier to load another page with the basci-print.css. For examle: <a href="basic-print-page" target="_blank">Print basic</a>.
I have corrected my jQuery answer, check again and test it out...

Comment: Sadly I can't adopt that method due to the complexity if the system I've built.  The code you have added also doesn't seem to work, do I need to add jQuery for it to work? Sorry don't really work with Java often :)

Comment: Yes you need to add <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> in your <head> tag. I'd like to bring your attention on the fact that jQuery is written in JavaScript which is different from Java (no connexion).

Comment: Sorry, I know the difference between Java and JS, was just typing lazily :)

Comment: BTW thanks, works a treat now, just need to make sure the print.css is referenced first otherwise the basic-print.css overrules the main style.css