# Stylesheet switcher button to toggle html when clicked (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I have a button at the top of my page that enables the use of a separate stylesheet for printing, I have a normal print.css that enables everything when printing and I have a acrfprint.css which just prints certain elements out.  Someone on here gave me some help getting this to work last week using the following JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#acrf').click(function(){
        $('link').first().removeAttr('href').attr('href', '_includes/css/acrfprint.css');
    });
});
</script>
```

This works perfectly but the only issue is that the button doesn't really give you any idea if the acrf-print.css has been enabled or how to disable it.

Basically the HTML I'm using it this:

```
<div id='acrfContaineroff'>
<button id='acrf' class='noPrint noPrint-acrf'>Enable Annotation Print Mode</button>
</div>
```

(I know I'm using ' instead of " but that's because it's nested in VBScript)

What I want to do is when the button is clicked, change the stylesheet to acrfprint.css and then display the following HTML instead

```
<div id='acrfContaineron'>
<button id='acrf' class='noPrint noPrint-acrf'>Disable Annotation Print Mode</button>
</div>
```

When the disable button is selected I want the css to return to print.css

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can look at you'r own previous questions, in case you wanted to link to it, and make it easier for everyone..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897149/how-to-print-web-page-with-a-different-stylesheet-other-than-print-css]

Comment: So, you want to switch stylesheets and also the text of the button?

Comment: @LShetty yeah, pretty much, just some sort of visual aid that the print.css has been changed to printacrf.css and for it to set back to print.css if it's clicked again.

Comment: @DaveBurns right. See my alswer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your questions look like you just started with javascript..
maybe you should just change the button to a checkbox?

```
<div id='acrfContaineroff'>
<button id='acrf' class='noPrint noPrint-acrf'>Enable Annotation Print Mode</button>
</div>
```

into:

```
<div id='acrfContaineroff'>
<input type='checkbox' id='acrf' /> Enable Annotation Print Mode
</div>
```

and the javascript into:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#acrf').click(function(){
        if( $('#acrf').is(':checked') ){
            $('link').first().removeAttr('href').attr('href', '_includes/css/acrfprint.css');
        }else{
            $('link').first().removeAttr('href').attr('href', '_includes/css/print.css');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect, this was my first idea but I couldn't quite work out how to do it, and you're right, JS is very new to me :)

Answer (score 2):

So, if you were after a stylesheet switcher on button click and also change the button label accordingly, this may help.

Assumption: Annotation print mode enabled = acrfprint.css

```
$('#acrf').click(function(){
    var label = "Disable Annotation Print Mode";
    var link = $('#myStylesheet');
    if (link.attr("href").indexOf("acrf") !== -1) {
        link.attr('href', '_includes/css/print.css');
        label = "Enable Annotation Print Mode";
    } else {
        link.attr('href', '_includes/css/acrfprint.css');
    }
    $(this).text(label);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='acrfContaineron'>
    <button id='acrf' class='noPrint noPrint-acrf'>Disable Annotation Print Mode</button>
</div>

<link id="myStylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_includes/css/acrfprint.css" />
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/zd0nz0j2/4/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I attempted it and it worked to a certain extent, however the guy witht he checkbox answer was the simplest method for what I required, thanks for your time though!

Comment: Very much so but I need to have a rating of 15 to do so :(

Answer (score 1):

you can use below demo created myself:
Let's assume that we have the following style sheets defined in our HEAD section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="blue" href="http://example.com/css/blue.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="pink" href="http://example.com/css/pink.css">
```

**HTML Code to Provide a Way for Your Users to Choose the Style Sheet**

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('blue');return false;" name="theme" value="Blue Theme" id="blue">
    <input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('pink');return false;" name="theme" value="Pink Theme" id="pink">
</form>
```

*JavaScript Function to Change Style Sheets*

```
        // *** TO BE CUSTOMISED ***

    var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
    var style_cookie_duration = 30 ;

    // *** END OF CUSTOMISABLE SECTION ***
    // You do not need to customise anything below this line

    function switch_style ( css_title )
    {
        // You may use this script on your site free of charge provided
        // you do not remove this notice or the URL below. Script from
        // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml
        var i, link_tag ;
        for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
          i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
            if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
              link_tag[i].title) {
                link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
                if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
                    link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
                }
            }
            set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
              style_cookie_duration );
        }
    }
    function set_style_from_cookie()
    {
        var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
        if (css_title.length) {
            switch_style( css_title );
        }
    }
    function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
        lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
    {
        // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
        var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                           ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
        document.cookie = cookie_name +
                           "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                           "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                           24 * lifespan_in_days +
                           "; path=/" + domain_string ;
    }
    function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
    {
        // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
        var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
        if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
            var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                            '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                            cookie_name +
                            '=([^;]*)' );
            return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
        }
        return '' ;
    }
```

you will also need to add an `onload` attribute to your web pages body tag :

```
<body onload="set_style_from_cookie()">
```

Comment: Sorry, that isn't relevant to what I'm trying to achieve, I already have another style switcher that does what your saying to toggle between the themes of the page.  I also want to avoid using form buttons as there isn't any need for them. And most importantly I don't need/want to use cookies for this part, I've set cookies purely for the theme switcher, just don't want to use cookies for the printacrf.css as only a handful of people will need to use it on an ahoc basis.  Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Afraid not, it would have been when I was writing the theme switcher, just not with the print switcher :)